# UnsupportedOperationException when returning Stream in Spring Data JPA repository method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to make use of the new Java 8 Stream support introduced in [Spring Data JPA 1.8 (Fowler)](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/26/what-s-new-in-spring-data-fowler#java-8-streams-in-repository-methods) by defining it as a return type for one of my repository methods.

```
interface CustomerRepository extends Repository<Customer, Long>
{
    Stream<Customer> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

When I run my application I encounter the following exception when I execute the repository method:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Streaming results is not implement for this PersistenceProvider: GENERIC_JPA
```

I am using Hibernate as my JPA provider but it doesn't look like Spring Data is able to detect it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue by altering the configuration of the EntityManagerFactory, I have specified the *entityManagerInterface* property as *org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManager* and Spring Data JPA is now able to detect the correct PersistenceProvider.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="entityManagerInterface" value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernateEntityManager" />
    ...
</bean>
```

It's likely I encountered this issue because I've introduced Spring Data JPA to an existing application which already had Hibernate/JPA configured. I suspect a project making use of something like Spring Boot with a typical configuration would not have encountered the same issue.

**EDIT:**
Just a quick followup, it's better to specify a `jpaVendorAdapter` if possible as it will automatically configure various aspects of the EntityManager including `entityManagerInterface`, `entityManagerFactoryInterface`, `persistenceProviderClass`, and `hibernate.dialect` which leaves less scope for missing something.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    ....
</bean>
```